# MonthCalendar: prevent view change

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I need to prevent the view change of a MonthCalendar.

I was able to prevent the view change like this:

```
private void WPF_S_MC_Calendar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (WPF_S_MC_Calendar.HitTest(e.Location).HitArea.ToString() == "TitleBackground")
   {
       WPF_S_MC_Calendar.Enabled = false;
       WPF_S_MC_Calendar.Enabled = true;
   }
}
```

But that prevent all the next events to be fired. 
So, someone know, if this is possible?

**EDIT**:
Another way would be to let the events to be fired and the scroll in the selected month again. The user wouldn't be able to see it.

Thank you guys.

Comment: try adding `e.handled = true` into that code.

Comment: When i do i got this error: **'MouseEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'handled' and no accessible extension method 'handled' accepting a first argument of type 'MouseEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**. The other way would be to write `return;` but it don't work to.

Comment: Well i do not use calender but it must work in some event inside it. As last resort create `private DateTime date` and store value of calender and on `ValidatED` event do `if (date != yourClaender.Value) { yourcalender.Value = date; }`

Comment: Or try `e.handled` inside `validatING` event, not sure if it will work since i am not in visual studio not to test it

Comment: You can create a new control derived from `MonthCalendar` and override `WndProc` method where you can place your checking logic. Basically you should skip the message if you are in the `"TitleBackground"` area and pass it to `base.WndProc` otherwise.

Comment: @AleksaRistic that's don't deactivate the view change.

Comment: @IliaMaskov thanks you for the info, I'll try to use that!

Comment: It would be great if you could post the answer if you found it yourself

Comment: I didn't found it, but that could be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137074/monthcalendar-in-net-expanding-a-month